# Duplicate question not able to flag

Tags: discussion

This is same question which is asked by three different users.

[Visualforce page loading very slow in production org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122806/visualforce-page-loading-very-slow-in-production-org)

[Page loading problem in production environment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122841/page-loading-problem-in-production-environment)

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122842/how-to-improve-loading-speed-of-visual-force-page-in-production#122842

Now either of them don't have any accepted answer so we can't flag them as duplicate. Also users are different here. So what is best in this case we can do like I am not sure if they are same user or may be three different user with some genuine problem.

Comment: Personally, I think this might be a case for self-answered question that could serve as a base for the other questions to be linked to. I don't think this happens very often, but I'd be interested in seeing what people have to say about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you had used the search feature with `[visualforce] page load time` as the search parameters, you'd have quickly found these posts that could have been referenced as duplicates:

[Advice on speeding up Visualforce pages?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/advice-on-speeding-up-visualforce-pages/15779#15779)

[Speed Up Page Load Time](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20739/speed-up-page-load-time)

[Approaches to debug a slow Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57871/approaches-to-debug-a-slow-visualforce-page/57872#57872)

Or the answer to the following closed question could also have been provided as a reference: [Apex / Visualforce / SOQL Performance](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113070/apex-visualforce-soql-performance/113071?s=18|0.3081#113071)

Comment: I have used that but unless there is an accepted answer. You can't reference that answer in closed. So only your 1 link is working here.

Comment: The 1st three should have worked fine for you. I gave the last one as a means of providing a suitable reference to use for a quick answer, not as a reason to close the question. The purpose of the forum is to provide answers to questions. If existing answers don't fully answer a question, then a question shouldn't be makred as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why this does not work previously.

Answer (score -2):

But if you can't help don't try to prove that you are very clever when it is not. It about author of post. You marked my question as dublicate but I think you didn't read it at all because questions are completely different.

Comment: If you read the another question and their answee then you Will know that  OP is facing same problem as your and you may find answer useful in your scenario. If that didn't work for you then you can add a comment of what didn't work for you and I will be very happy to nominate your question for reopening. I hope this will help you.

Comment: You can to recomend me another question but not to say that it's similar when you don't know issue. And when you mark question as duplicate I can't get answers so people will not help me. "Thank you".

Comment: We can-and will-use our discretion to close posts as needed. A post being flagged as duplicate does not reflect negatively on the asker, but lashing out afterward does. If you feel your question should be reopened, you should update your post with more info, instead of attacking the moderators.

Comment: I understood, if people have some more power than someone else he use it everywhere whether it need or no(